Ray tune checkpoints for training a YOLOv8 network
I've been trying to train my own fine-tuned network with the YOLOv8 architecture, and I also want to optimize hyperparameters and find the best parameters for data augmentation. Now, I'm seeking to find the best parameters possible, but I couldn't find how to save checkpoints from YOLOv8 ray tuning since the training lasts many hours. There is nothing about checkpointing in the original YOLOv8 Ray tuning docs: YOLOv8 Ray Tune docs.
There is probably a way to do it since there is a page about checkpointing on the original Ray Tune webpage: original docs, but I have no idea how to implement it in the example code:
from ultralytics import YOLO

# Load a YOLOv8n model
model = YOLO('yolov8n.pt')

# Start tuning hyperparameters for YOLOv8n training on the COCO8 dataset
result_grid = model.tune(data='coco8.yaml', use_ray=True)


from ultralytics import YOLO

# Load a YOLOv8n model
model = YOLO('yolov8n.pt')

clsObject = ['persona', 'bicycle', 'car', 'motorcycle', 'airplane', 'bus', 'train', 'truck', 'boat', 'traffic light','fire hydrant', 'stop sign', 'parking meter', 'bench', 'bird', 'cat', 'dog', 'horse', 'sheep','cow', 'elephant', 'bear', 'zebra', 'giraffe', 'backpack', 'umbrella', 'handbag', 'tie', 'suitcase', 'frisbee','skis', 'snowboard', 'sports ball', 'kite', 'baseball bat', 'baseball glove', 'skateboard', 'surfboard', 'tennis racket', 'bottle', 'wine glass', 'cup', 'fork', 'knife', 'spoon', 'bowl', 'banana', 'apple', 'sandwich', 'orange', 'broccoli', 'carrot', 'hot dog', 'pizza', 'donut', 'cake', 'chair', 'couch', 'potted plant', 'bed',  'dining table', 'toilet', 'tv', 'laptop', 'mouse', 'remote', 'keyboard', 'cell phone', 'microwave', 'oven',    'toaster', 'sink', 'refrigerator', 'book', 'clock', 'vase', 'scissors', 'teddy bear', 'hair drier', 'toothbrush']

text_obj = f'{self.clsObject[cls]}'

size_obj, thickness_obj = 0.75, 1

frame = self.draw_text(frame, (0, 255, 0), text_obj, x1, y1, size_obj, thickness_obj, back=True)

frame = self.draw_area(frame, (0, 0, 255), x1, y1, x2, y2)


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
